# How do I get redmine's activity log to show repository changes automatically?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I wrote a [little python script](https://bitbucket.org/sdolan/bitbucket-watcher) to accept BitBucket POST callbacks of repository changes and update the local copy.  That all works fine, but I noticed that redmine's activity log doesn't show those changes until I click on the repository tab.

Is there a way to trigger the activity log update programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misunderstood your question in IRC, you can find the answer to your question [in the redmine faq](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/FAQ#Commits-dont-show-up-in-the-activity-until-I-click-on-Repository)

Comment: Thank you, this looks like just what I need.  I'll give it a shot tomorrow and update my repo accordingly.